# Reading properties in properties file with ant not respects order

Tags: file, ant, properties, task

Reading properties in properties file with ant not respects order.

The order is not respected:

Example:

```
<property file="build.properties" prefix="prefix."/>
<propertyselector property="cases" match="prefix.project\.(.*)" select="\1"/>
<for list="${cases}" param="pr">
<sequential>
<echo message="Project: @{pr} Version: ${prefix.project.@{pr}}"/>
</sequential>
</for>
```

with:

build.properties

```
project.1 = 1.2.3
project.8 = 5.9.4
project.4 = 3.5.0
```

Get:

```
 Project: 8 Version 5.9.4
 Project: 1 Version 1.2.3
 Project: 4 Version 3.5.0
```

(And the result seems to randomly change)
I have to build them in the order like they appear in the build.properties file ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property file is being read in the correct order. You can test this by simply putting in duplicate properties and see which one gets defined. Here's `build.properties`:

```
dup.prop = foo
dup.prop = bar
```

And here's my Ant script:

```
<project>
    <property file="build.properties"/>
    <echo>Dup.prop is set to "${dup.prop}".</echo>
</project>
```

Running this, I'll get:

```
Dup.prop is set to "foo".
```

That's because the value *foo* is defined first in `build.properies`, and once a property is defined, it cannot be (easily) changed.

What you're trying to do is to access the properties in the order they're defined. That isn't guaranteed because properties are stored in a hash.

You mention sub-projects, and those sub-projects must be built in a particular order. Unfortunately, it's hard to tell exactly what could be the issue since you didn't give us an outline of your actual issue and some sample build scripts for projects and sub-projects.

First, Ant is a *build matrix language* which means it has a dependency hierarchy. The biggest issue developers have is attempting to force build matrix languages to execute in a particular order. You should specify a dependency hierarchy in your build.xml files (and the fewer there are, the easier it is for Ant to get things right).

If sub-project "B" depends upon a jar file in sub-project "A", It should be in sub-project "B"'s Ant script a dependency on sub-project "A" jar build.

```
<project name="proj-b"/>
    ...
    <target name="build-jar"
        depends="test.if.jar.exists"
        unless="jar.exist">
        <ant directory="${proj.a.dir}"
           target="build.depend.jar"/>
    </target>

    <target name="test.if.jar.exists">
        <condition property="jar.exists">
           <available file="${proj.a.dir}/dist/${dend.jar.file}"/>
        </condition>
    </target>

    <target name="compile"
        depends="build-jar">
        ....
    </target>
    ...
</project>
```

In the above `build.xml` for Project "B", I depend upon some jar file that Project "A" builds before I can compile Project "B". Therefore, my `compile` task depends upon `build-jar` which will build Target "A"'s jar file. To prevent this task from building Project "A"'s jar over and over, I use `<condition>` as a test to see if this jar exists. If it already does, I don't rebuild the jar.

In this case:

- Target "compile" is called. That target realizes it depends upon Target "build-jar".
- Before Target "compile" is executed. Target "build-jar" is first called.
- Target "build-jar" depends upon Target "test.if.jar.exists".
- Before "build-jar" is executed, it calls Target "test.if.jar.exists"
- In Target "test.if.jar.exists", if the jar already exists, the property `jar.exists` will be set.
- Now, Target "build-jar" is active, and looks to see if the property `jar.exists` is set. If it is, the target won't execute.
- Finally, control returns to Target "compile" which then executes.

Here I'm not enforcing order directly. Instead, I merely have a dependency hierarchy that I specify, and I let Ant figure out exactly what to do.

If dependent jar issues are a big issue, you can also look into [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy). Ivy allows you to create a *Jar Repository*. Your projects that build jars the rest of your projects are dependent upon can fetch the needed jars from this repository. This is very similar to Maven. In fact, Ant with Ivy can use Maven repositories. We use [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview), a local Maven repository manager, for our Ant projects.

You can also try the [`<subant>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html) task which does allow you to specify a *buildpath* which would allow you to say *build sub-project "A" before sub-project "B"*. You can define the *buildpath* in another Ant XML file which could be dependent upon customer and then use `<import>` to import the build path for that project.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed. Java properties are represented with a `java.util.Hashtable`, and as you surely know, hash tables do not preserve order. You simply cannot do what you want with a properties file.

If those "projects" that you state you want to build in order are in turn Ant projects, you may want to consider moving their tasks to your main build-file instead, and simply enforce the proper building order using normal Ant dependencies.

Comment: This main ant task is my packaging project which call other ant subprojects build but I cannnot move their tasks at its level because depending on customer, some projects will have to be built, other not.

Comment: I don't see how that prevents you from moving the tasks, however. If you have one build-file with all the tasks in it, you could simply call it to build the tasks you want, depending on the customer.

Comment: For exemple, I have one only main project, which have to be built before any other, so in my main ant, have to iterate twice on my list :
First only to detect if this main project is declared into the properties file (if yes, to call its build task) and another for-loop to build other one. It's not a smart solution but it works until an other project was declared and that this project have to be built in second position before others...

If I could do what I want the litte part of this second project would be integrated as API part in the first one but I cannot take this decision.

Comment: Because embeding all tasks of all subprojects with their own special seems to be...not smart and difficult to maintain this huge script.

Comment: If anything, you could use <include> tags to include the requisite projects in those that depend on them.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will help to sort the list generated by propertyselector tag

```
<sortlist property="my.sorted.list" value="${my.list}"
             delimiter="," />
<echo message="${my.sorted.list}" />
```